# TypeError: $(...).substring is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through every selected element to truncate it to ~ 10 letters.

However I'm getting a `TypeError: $(...).substring is not a function` and not sure why. Here's my code:

```
$('.post_text_div h1').each(function (e) {
    var truncated = $(this).substring(0, 10)
    // console.log('Truncated:', truncated);
    $(this).text(truncated);
});
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Because... i mean, it's not a function. jQuery collections have no such function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) on the text of the element, not on the element itself:

Change

```
var truncated = $(this).substring(0, 10)
```

To

```
var truncated = $(this).text().substring(0, 10)
```